# How to cause delay of 1 second of bullets when space pressed

Tags: java, timer

I was wondering how to cause the bullets to delay since at the moment, they fire pretty much one after another. So I was wondering how to make each bullet be delayed by one second when the space bar is pressed/held down.

```
public class TheGun extends GunType{

  private Rectangle bullet;
  private final double speed = 3d;

  public TheGun(double xPos, double yPos, int width,int height){
    this.setxPos(xPos);
    this.setyPos(yPos);
    this.setWidth(width);
    this.setHeight(height);

    this.bullet = new Rectangle((int) getxPos(),(int) getyPos(), getWidth(), getHeight());
  }

  @Override
  public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    if(bullet == null)
      return;

    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fill(bullet);
  }

  @Override
  public void update(double delta, BlockyBlocks blocks) {
    if(bullet == null)
      return;

    this.setyPos(getyPos() - (delta * speed - 1));
    bullet.y = (int) this.getyPos();
    wallCollide(blocks);
    isOutofBounds();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean collisionRect(Rectangle rect) {
    if(this.bullet == null)
      return false;

    if(bullet.intersects(rect)){
      this.bullet = null;
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean collisionPoly(Polygon poly) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean destroy() {
    if(bullet == null)
      return true;

    return false;
  }

  @Override
  protected void wallCollide(BlockyBlocks blocks) {
    for(int i = 0; i < blocks.wall.size(); i++){
      if(bullet.intersects(blocks.wall.get(i))){
        blocks.wall.remove(i);
        bullet = null;
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void isOutofBounds() {
    if(this.bullet == null)
      return;

    if(bullet.y < 0 || bullet.y > Sea_InvadersDisplay.HEIGHT || bullet.x < 0 || bullet.x > Sea_InvadersDisplay.WIDTH){
      bullet = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should really stick to a single naming style when programming.

Comment: In the future, you can use the "Code sample" button from the edit toolbar to format your code.

Answer (score 2):

What you can simply do is keeping the last bullet launched time, and when trying to fire check if the ellapsed time is over 1 second to launch the next bullet.

It could look like this

```
uint timeLastBullet = 0; // Initialize before game loop

if (spacePressed) // In game loop
{
    if (GetTime() - timeLastBullet >= 1000) //If GetTime returns milliseconds
    {
        Fire();
        timeLastBullet = GetTime();
    }
}
```